# Replace numbers, dash, dot or space from the start of a string with PHP regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace numbers with optional, dash, dot or space from the start of a string, my pattern does not seem to work. 
I want to replace this:

```
01. PHP
02  HTML5
03. - CSS3
```

with

```
PHP
HTML5
CSS3
```

My code is below:

```
$t = trim($_POST['test']);
$pattern = '/^[\d{0,4}(. -)?]/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $t)){
    echo preg_replace($pattern,'', $t);
}else{
    echo 'No';
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex - `/^[\d{0,4}(. -)?]/` - matches the beginning of the string, and then **1 character**: either a digit, or a `{`, or a `0`, or a `,`, or a `}`, or a `(`, or a dot, or a range from space to `)` (i.e. a space, `!"#$%&'` and a `)`, or a question mark. So, it can only work in a limited number of case you describe.

Just use

```
preg_replace('/^[\d .-]+/','', $t);
```

Here,

- `^` - matches beginning of string/line
- `[\d .-]+` matches a digit, space, dot or hyphen, 1 or more timesd

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cX8uD8/1)

Nogte that if you have multiple lines, you need `(?m)` modifier.

```
preg_replace('/(?m)^[\d .-]+/','', $t);
```

Here is an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/SuIt2f)

**NOTE**: If you plan to remove anything that is not letter from the beginning of the string, I'd recommend using [`^\P{L}+` regex](https://regex101.com/r/cX8uD8/4) with `u` modifier.

Comment: @slartidan the code you gave remove all the numbers, the are some cases where the number is part of string like `12. 3Lau` and get `3Lau`

Comment: @ TurnTheTables I think your comment was directed at @stribizhev

Comment: @TurnTheTables: in case the whitespace and hyphens must come after a number, you can try `preg_replace('/^\s*\d*[ .-]+/','', $t);`

Answer (score 1):

Can try [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/fU0qZ2/1)

```
$t = "01. PHP";

$pattern = '/^[0-9\.\s\-]+/';

echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $t);
```

**Output**

```
PHP
```

**Regex Explanation**

```
^ assert position at start of the string
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
\. matches the character . literally
\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
\- matches the character - literally
```

Comment: According to [this comment from the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638344/replace-numbers-dash-dot-or-space-from-the-start-of-a-string-with-php-regex#comment51231634_31638380), greedily trimming all of these characters at the start of each line will compromise the values that should not be modified.